# Need help resolving weird fscanf issue

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to read from a file line by line by running it through a while loop which is instructed to exit once EOF has been reached. But for some reason once the last line has been read and the while condition is checked again the program just freezes.

This is my code:

```
char character1;
int number1;

while(fscanf(file,"%s %d",&character1, &number1) != EOF){
    //printf("%s %d\n",character1,number1) 
}
```

My files contents:

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4
E 5
```

Output:

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4
E 5
|    <---Blinking terminal pointer currently there
```

Can anyone help me figure this out?

EDIT: I am not opening/closing the file in main(), I am doing it in another function, could this be causing a problem?

Comment: use `" %c` instead of  `"%s`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY just did, sadly, im getting the same results.

Comment: Input waiting (or infinite loop?) is present in other parts

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I checked to make sure of that. Any printf added after the while loop doesnt get printed, implying that the while loop never exits.

Comment: Check the result of `fscanf`, not just for `EOF`. How many entries have been read? Provide a [mcve]. And use a debugger to see where it hangs.

Comment: Content other than those presented in the file are included.

Comment: try [this](http://ideone.com/nPzE1Z)

Comment: I got it working by moving the fopen to my main. I have no idea why fscanf is not working as intended in a sub function but working fine in main.

Comment: At least such a code must be included in the post.

Comment: **fscanf** returns integers , 0 when eof is reached, EOF is a symbolic constant returned by **char fgetc(fp)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improve the condition checking on the while loop. The fscanf() can produce more results that EOF or a positive number. It can also return a positive number when an end-of-file occurs after conversion has begun. Meaning that you have something going wrong with a conversion and so the data is still there the next time you loop around to get more data from the stream. So you are stuck infinitely failing to convert that same failed conversion.

You are looking for 2 input items so check that the fscanf() has found 2 input items in order to continue looping.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your fscanf reads the \r or \n in the end of every line. Just creates a buffer to ignore it and will be fine. I did the following and it worked smoothly.

```
char character1;
int number1;
char buffer[2]; // will read the end of line

while(fscanf(file,"%c %d",&character1, &number1) != EOF){
    fgets(buffer, 2, file);// does the job
    printf("[%c] [%d]\n",character1,number1);
}
```